# How can one pass both a JSHandle and a native object (String) to Puppeteer evaluate functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I can pass native objects (strings, lists, numbers, etc) or JSHandle just fine (thanks to @hardkoded), but have no clue HOW to bass BOTH at the same time

This is my code right now, with the string (deployName) hardcoded inside the body:

```
async clickClientDeploymentsActionLink(deployName) {
    const rowsHandle = await this.getRows();
    await rowsHandle.evaluate(node => { 
        // need to figure HOW to pass both a string and a JSHandle
        let deployName = 'Distributed Selene 8.2';
        var children = []
        for(x = 0; x < node.length; x++) {
            if (node[x].childElementCount > 0) {
                children.push(node[x]);
            }
        }
        let childNode = null
        for(y = 0; y < children.length; y++) {
            if (children[y].innerText.includes(deployName)) {
                childNode = children[y];
                break
            }
        } 
        let actionNode = null;
        for(z = 0; z < childNode.childNodes.length; z++) {
            if (childNode.childNodes[z].innerText == 'Actions') {
                actionNode = childNode.childNodes[z];
                break;
            }
        }
        actionNode.click()
    });
}
```

This works perfectly, but I need to figure how to pass also the string variable, and can't seem to figure how since handles and variables are passed differently (example of how I pass variables like strings, which totally works):

```
    async rowsChildrenCount(id='dashboardGrid') {
        const children = await this.page.evaluate(({id}) => { 
            const grid = document.getElementById(id)
            const rows = grid.getElementsByClassName('ag-row')
            var children = []
            for(x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
                if (rows[x].childElementCount > 0) {
                    children.push(rows[x].childElementCount);
                }
            }
            return children
        }, {id});
```

UPDATE: hardkoded suggested a solution (what I did before, but adding '(node, itemName)' to the evaluate), but it didn't seem to work,

```
    async clickItemActionLink(itemName) {
        const rowsHandle = await this.getRows();
        await rowsHandle.evaluate((node, itemName) => { 
            var children = []
            for(x = 0; x < node.length; x++) {
                if (node[x].childElementCount > 0) {
                    children.push(node[x]);
                }
            }
            let childNode = null
            for(y = 0; y < children.length; y++) {
                if (children[y].innerText.includes(itemName)) {
                    childNode = children[y];
                    break
                }
            } 
            let actionNode = null;
            for(z = 0; z < childNode.childNodes.length; z++) {
                if (childNode.childNodes[z].innerText == 'Actions') {
                    actionNode = childNode.childNodes[z];
                    break;
                }
            }
            actionNode.click()
        });
    }
```

That gets "**Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null**" on account of itemName being null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a function where the first argument is always the `JSHandle` but the rest of them are values you can pass to the evaluate function.

```js
await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204241/how-can-one-pass-both-a-jshandle-and-a-native-object-string-to-puppeteer-evalu");
const title = await page.$(".js-products-menu");
await title.evaluate((node, text) => node.innerText = text, "Foo");
```

Comment: Hey hardkoded! Thanks for the reply, however I'm afraid I tried already to no avail:

`
    const rowsHandle = await this.getRows();
    await rowsHandle.evaluate((node, itemName) => {........});
`

And I get error due to itemName is null.

I updated the above original post to show this code properly since I can't properly put it here

Comment: You need to pass itemName to the evaluate function as I'm doing with "Foo"

Comment: Damn, I must be getting dumber alongside older!
Didn't notice (due to the lack of {}) that "Foo" was the passed variable in your example.
Thanks again! If I come back again (for a different question) I might have to start paying you a savior's fee...

Comment: OK, besides voting up your reply, how exactly does one "upvote" someone else (I'm actually new actually putting up questions)? I already marked it as the correct one (so I don't miss doing whatever else I should be doing).

Comment: @silvakle https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments :)

Comment: Yeah, already did that right off the bat "besides voting up your reply".